# AngularFireModule shared across entire Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I have a project with multiple modules and components. Currently I am initializing AngularFireModule in every module so that I can use firebase database/authentication info in components under that module. I feel like it is not necessary to initialize AngularFireModule this many time and that I am not understanding something.

```
//app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),   //<----
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ],
  providers: [AngularFireModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I thought about creating a service that inits AngularFireModule and all modules/components can use the service...then I noticed I have about 5 services that talk to firebase. It would mean the application initializes firebase at least 5 times, one in each service. What is the best way to have access to firebase in large projects?

Comment: You can just create a shared module that initializes your firebase, then all your other modules can just lay a dependency on your shared module

Answer (score 0):

I learned couple of options. Having it in AppModule would enable other sub modules use it as well. Also having it initialize in one service and using that service from any other services would make it that the initialize code is at one place.

from angular docs :

> AngularJS services are:
>
> Lazily instantiated – AngularJS only instantiates a service when an
>   application component depends on it.
>
> Singletons – Each component dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance generated by the service factory.